# OnBeforeResponse have it pass parameter url in excel instead of open in chrome

Tags: c#, .net, excel, fiddler, process.start

If you know about `OnBeforeResponse` then you know what I am trying to do.

How can I make it paste the URL in excel file instead of opening each and every URL in chrome or Firefox

from

```
  if(oSession.url.Contains(".mp3")){
            FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("downloading "+oSession.url);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe",oSession.url);
        }
```

what I tried so far.

```
 if(oSession.url.Contains(".mp3")){
            FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("downloading "+oSession.url);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("excel.exe",oSession.url);
        }
```

I am also trying to use `cmd.exe` to output each `oSession.url` to `>` somefile.txt.

Comment: Please see edit. I have updated it.

Comment: I would suggest learning your tools before attempting something more advanced like this.  Perhaps starting with the ubiquitous "Hello World" and moving on from there.

Comment: sorry, but I don't need whole language of C# to get there. that's why I posted here for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am also trying cmd.exe output each oSession.url to > somefile.txt.

If you are merely trying to scrape the MP3 urls into a file for some later use, then the idea of outputting them to `somefile.txt` seems simpler than trying to interact with Excel from FiddlerScript.

Add the following line (to your code), which accomplishes appending the latest MP3 url to `somefile.txt` (note: I placed my text file in a particular folder):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c echo " + oSession.url + " >> c:\\temp\\somefile.txt")
```

The file will accumulate the MP3 urls as you click.  Hope that helps.

Comment: If the songname data is part of the URL then it should get written to the TXT file using the code above.  The line breaks in the text file should make it easy to import it into Excel and use it.

Comment: Assign your Bounty manually (before the expiration and grace) and you'll pick up a **Benefactor Badge**. http://stackoverflow.com/badges

Answer (score 1):

probably you want this
[using fiddler to automatically download mp3s](http://improve.dk/using-fiddler-to-automatically-download-streamed-mp3s/)

Comment: I am using similar to that, using Fiddler script intead, I think David Tansey's solution is what I am looking for but I haven't had chance to test it at home. I am currently I work.